# Networkx pygraphviz graphviz_layout arguments not working

Tags: python, plotly, networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have a graph built with networkx and graphviz in Python using pygraphviz and networkx's graphviz_layout it is then displayed in Plotly.

I wish to change the space between nodes of the graph.

I currently have the graph displayed in plotly like this:
[image]

However, when I try to use args on the graph to change the distance between nodes like so:

```
pos=graphviz_layout(G,prog='dot',args='-Gnodesep="10.0" -Granksep="1.0"')
```

I do not see any changes on the plotly plot. Am I doing something wrong with the args?